# Laravel5.7 : how to store nested arrays to database

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.7.
Designing an app with many views containing forms.
 
In this view:
- there is one (only one) client_id field. This is hidden and the value is retrieved from an url segment.
- other fields are dynamic (date, type, comments) and refers to one or more products bought by this client.
**I cannot figure out how to save input values from the dynamic fieds to the database (sorry, I am quite new to coding)**
See below my current code and attempts.
*I found related answers in stack overflow could not make them fit to my case.*
I would appreciate help

***STORE() FUNCTION IN CONTROLLER***

```
public function storeDYNarray(Request $request)
    {
        $client = $request->input('client_id');
        $all = $request->input();
        $products = $request->input('product');
        //dd($all); SEE BELOW

//THIS CREATES AS MANY NEW ENTRIES IN PRODUCTS TABLE AS NEEDED WITH THE CORRESPONDING client_ID
        foreach ($products as $product){
            $dia = new Product;
            //client_id is retrieved from an URL segment
            $dia->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
//DON'T KNOW HOW TO SAVE VALUES FROM THE DYNAMIC FIELDS
            $dia->save();
    }
```

***my best shot(amont many not worth showing)***

```
 public function storeDYNarray(Request $request)
    {
        $client = $request->input('client_id');
        $all = $request->input();
        $products = $request->input('product');
        $i=1;
        $client_products[$i] = array();

        foreach ($products as $product){
            while ($i<=count($products)){
                $client_products[$i] = new Product(array(
                    'client_id' => $client,
                    'product_date' => $products[$i]['date'],
                    'product_type' => $products[$i]['type'],
                    'product_comment' => $products[$i]['comment'],
                ));
                $client_products[$i]->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
//this returns Undefined index errors
```

***return dd($all); OUTPUT***

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "uvtLaCiuAueBIuyWkoCoOTdQzYB1paxhnLw0lbyO"
  "client_id" => "898"
  "product" => array:2 [▼
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "date" => "2019-03-13"
      "type" => "new"
      "comment" => "surplus"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "date" => "2019-03-28"
      "type" => "used"
      "comment" => "good condition"
    ]
  ]
]
```

***PRODUCTS TABLE***

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        //KEPT VALIDATION PARAMETERS SIMPLE FOR KNOW
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('client_id')->nullable($value = true); 
            $table->date('product_date')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('product_type')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->longText('comment_about_product')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

***PRODUCT MODEL***

```
class product extends Model
{
    //GIVEN THE STRUCTURE OF ARRAYS WHEN dd($all); I DONT THINK I NEED THAT
    /*
    public $fillable = [
        'client_id',
        'product_date',
        'product_type',
        'product_comment', 
    ];
    */

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\client');
        }
}
```

***CLIENT TABLE***

```
<?php
//use Illuminate...
class CreateclientsTable extends Migration
{ 
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('client_id');
            $table->primary('client_id');
            //other columns...
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

***CLIENT MODEL***

```
class client extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\product');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `storeDYNarray` function you are never incrementing `$i`. And since you are comparing `$i` against the number of products in a `while` loop, it will run forever. Also, unless I am missing something, the `while` loop is unneeded since you are using the `foreach` loop. Here is an adjusted version of the `storeDYNarray` function. It has not been tested, but will hopefully help you in the right direction:

```
public function storeDYNarray(Request $request)
{
    $client = $request->input('client_id');
    $products = $request->input('product');

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        Product::create([
            'client_id' => $client,
            'product_date' => $product['date'],
            'product_type' => $product['type'],
            'product_comment' => $product['comment'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

You will also need to uncomment your `$fillable` property on your `Product` Model for the previous code to work.

Comment: Hi, this is still throwing me an "Undefined index" error, don't know why. Yes, I don't need a 'foreach' loop and a 'while' loop. I am rather tempted to use the 'while' loop: the [$i] is the index for the fields fields. Based on my javascript code, when the user add a new product, added fields will have an index of 2 (ex: the input date 'name' will be '[product][2][date]') and the output for 'count($products)' is 2. Do you still think it will run forever?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work afterall, not sure this is the best way but this works.

```
public function storeDYNarray(Request $request)


     {
            $client = $request->input('client_id');
            $all = $request->input();
            $products = $request->input('product');
            $i=1;
            while($i<=count($products)){
                $client_product[$i]=array(
                    $products[$i]['date'], //0
                    $products[$i]['type'], //1
                    $products[$i]['comment'] //2
                );
                $i++;
            }

            $i=1;
            foreach($products as $products){
                while($i<=count($diagnoses)){
                    $product = new Product;
                    $product->client_id = $client;
                    $product->product_date = $client_product[$i][0];
                    $product->product_type = $client_product[$i][1];
                    $product->product_comment = $client_product[$i][2];
                    $product->save();
                    $i++;
                }    
            }
        }
```

...and I uncommented the $fillable property on the model.